# Dropbox: Get a list of files and file-content using username and password

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

What is the simplest way to get **a list of files and read their content using only username and password** in C#?

Imagine a Console-app with **no GUI**, so **no popping up any dialog-windows** for authentication on the Dropbox-site.

Comment: maybe try some dropboxAPI's https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/other

Comment: @wudzik They seem to all rely on OAuth or they are outdated.

Answer (score 4):

The Dropbox API does not support username/password authentication. OAuth in the browser is required to do the initial authentication, but from then on you can store and reuse the OAuth credentials you get back.

Comment: It is possible for a command-line app to provide the user with a URL which they can hit in their browser to get authorized.  Then after that the app can store the resulting token so the auth process doesn't need to repeat on every run.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use C# Api? you should look at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/other.
Position: C# .NET on codeplex by Dirk, look at documentation http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/documentation you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: The version of SharpBox that comes in the latest NuGet-package (updated 2011-10-29) seem broken and doesn't seem to contain the Dropbox-functionality described on CodePlex.